how could engineers find pressure loss location in jet engines?
What are the tools, software or devices that jet engineers use to know if there is loss of pressure in the air? Are they using only calculations to know how much air in vs out?
It's very interesting to know how they could find pressure loss when they design their jet engine exactly in order to reduce it?

What do you mean exactly with pressure loss?

for example, when the fan sucks the air or the compressor, what I know is there is some loss of compressed air, so stator blades angle help handle that to avoid losing much pressure. so, I WANT to know how they measure pressure and see if there is loss of pressure once enters the compressor and get compressed

"stator blades angle help handle that to avoid losing much pressure" actually the stator blades do create the pressure losses you are talking about but they are anyway necessary to guide the flow towards the next compressor stage. Some other pressure/energy is lost due to the not perfectly sealed interface between blades and outer wall. Is this what you mean?

Pressure loss is something you encounter due to the shape of the inlet, fundamental pressure loss of heating air, etc. So designing for minimal pressure loss is designing a machine using the laws of aerodynamics. Gas turbines are designed to have minimal pressure loss, encountering a sudden pressure loss in the air is just a different operating condition. Your question is not clear. Please note, shouting (using capitals) is usually frowned upon, please improve your question.

Pressure loss is not the only and also not the most important variable governing engine performance. In general, engineers try to compare calculated performance number such as pressure, temperature, flow velocities, mechanical stress and other parameters to calculated metrics. This way, the performance of the engine can be validated and compared to the expected performance which was calculated during the design phase of the engine. For these tests, a couple of engines are instrumented with suitable test equipment which shall measure some of these numbers at critical locations throughout the engine.
I tried to summarize some measurement techniques in the following list (which is by no means comprehensive):

Pressure and temperature probes: Simple pressure or temperature probes which can be inserted into the casing at various points

Velocity probes throughout the flow section: Pressure transducer inserted into the casing to give spatial distribution of flow. See the following picture


Strain gauges: These instruments measure the lengthening of a blade for example and can be used to calculate mechanical stress


Optical beams: These devices are inserted such that their beam is aiming at the rotating blades of the engine. This technique can be used to gather additional information about the flow around the rotor blades



Please note that I took all of the images out of MTUs Measurement techniques and instrumentation  company leaflet. Other resources can be found for example here or here. Especially the first source gives a good thorough overview.
I hope this gives a very rough overview.
